# Mapbox GL - my basic, default marker won´t show up on the map

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

lately, I started fiddling with MapBox and right now, I am trying to add the marker to the map. Not as easy as it seems. I am trying to **add basic, default marker** with code copypasted straight out of ["Mapbox GL" reference guide](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Marker). Still, it won´t show up.

This is the code I use, it cant get simpler that this...

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([45.702117, 42.395926]).addTo(map);
```

Does anybody have an idea why it doesnt work? Whole "not working scenario" can be seen at http://www.caucasus-trekking.com/Maps/map

Edit: Specifically, I would like to use that classic marker, round at the top and pointy at the bottom. Somjething like this - https://www.mapbox.com/help/img/android/marker-example.png

Wasnt there some default shape in Mapbox or should I create it by my own css file?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhat strangely, it appears that the answer is that the Marker is being drawn, but there is no styling included in mapbox-gl.css to actually make it visible. It's just an invisible div.

So you need to add some CSS:

```
.mapboxgl-marker {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:1px solid gray;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

See codepen: https://codepen.io/stevebennett/pen/VpPbbM

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I just added reference to "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.32.1/mapbox-gl.css" and thought it contained some default objects.
So I should download and edit that css locally, right? Specifically, I would like to use that classis "tear" marker, round at the top and pointy at the bottom. Thought it was a default marker for mapbox.

Comment: I wouldn't edit it. I'd create your own stylesheet and load that in addition. As far as I can tell, there is no default teardrop marker style present.

Answer (score 3):

If you look into the source of your page, you'll see that the marker is successfully added as an empty `<div class="mapbox-gl-marker" ...></div>`. Yes, nothing to see here, but that's the default way it is.

Show that marker some love and give it some style.

```
var el = document.createElement('div');                                       
el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://placekitten.com/g/50/)';              
el.style.width = '50px';                                                      
el.style.height = '50px';
el.style.borderRadius = '50%';                                                     
new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat([45.702117, 42.395926]).addTo(map);
```

See the original source of this c&p code in [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/).

Comment: Thank you, got it. I actually saw that example before, but didnt use it as I want that classic marker, round at the top and pointy at the bottom. Do I have to specifically design it via css? Thought it was a default shape for Mapbox.

Comment: I am using React and it does not show, see my code sample : 
                                                                                              property.forEach((property) => {
      return new mapboxgl.Marker({
        draggable: false,
        color: '#2196f3',
      })
        .setLngLat([property.longx_decimal, property.laty_decimal])
        .setPopup(
          new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 20 }).setHTML(` 
            <>
              HTML sample text`
            </>
            `)
        )
        .addTo(mapp);
    });

Answer (score 1):

After carefully reading docs I realize this issue occurs because we are not importing `mapbox-js.css` file. Please read the docs to know how to add it https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#quickstart.

Comment: In my case I have the CSS imported but it still does not show up